# How do I split a string into three parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the string `"001-1776591-7"`, and I want to divide it into 3 parts, `"-"` being the `split` parameter.

I have already created two methods, for the first and last, but what about the second part of the string, how can I get that?

---

More Info:

I created the two methods in my Class, but when loading the view I get an error, details below:

```
  def serie
      @serie || cedula.to_s.split('-').[0] : @serie
  end

  def identificador
      @identificador || cedula.to_s.split('-').[1] : @identificador
 end

 def verificador
      @verificador || cedula.to_s.split('-').[2] : @verificador
 end


SyntaxError in TecnicosController#index

/home/lurraca/Desktop/rails_project/ArLink/app/models/tecnico.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '['
          @serie || cedula.to_s.split('-').[0] : @serie
                                           ^
/home/lurraca/Desktop/rails_project/ArLink/app/models/tecnico.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected '['
...dor || cedula.to_s.split('-').[1] : @identificador
...                              ^
/home/lurraca/Desktop/rails_project/ArLink/app/models/tecnico.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected '['
          @verificador || cedula.to_s.split('-').[2] : @verificador
```

Comment: Notice that the syntax error is specifying the `'['` as being unexpected. Indexes into arrays do not use `.[]` format, instead they should be `[]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `split` method returns an array, so you can access the second element of it the same way you would get the second element of any other array: `array[1]`.  Also, using the `||` bar can make your code simpler.  Try this:

```
def serie
   @serie || cedula.to_s.split('-')[0]
end

def banana
   @banana || cedula.to_s.split('-')[1]
end

def verificador
   @verificador || cedula.to_s.split('-')[2]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I added more info to my original question, hope you can help with that.

Comment: You are getting syntax errors because you did not copy my code exactly!  There should be no period before the `[`.

Comment: How about using `||=` here to save the results for later invocations?

Comment: This works. My bad with the syntax error while copying, the data is persisting in my db. One issue i'm having is while trying to edit an instance of the model, the field cedula is not being displayed in my view.

Comment: @Lars: Using `||=` here is OK depending on how you want the method to behave.  The original poster did not specify that he wanted to have the method to behave that way, so I didn't use `||=`.

Answer (score 9):

Why not set them all at once?

```
@serie, @identificador, @verificador = cedula.split('-')
```

You can make them attributes via `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader` if you still want to access them via methods.

Answer (score 5):

```
cedula.to_s.split('-')[1]
```

`split` returns an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
cedula.to_s.split('-')[0] is the same as cedula.to_s.split('-').first

cedula.to_s.split('-')[1] is the second part of your string

cedula.to_s.split('-').last is the last part in this case the third which can be accessed        via: cedula.to_s.split('-')[2] as well


> cedula.to_s.split('-')
=> ["001", "1776591", "7"]
```

Split splits a string into an Array. Elements of an array can be accessed the following way:

array[0], array[1] etc...

An array begins from 0.